# Photo posted from fan on my page doesn't show up in Graph (Facebook Graph API)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, photo

Photos posted (on the page Wall) by fans go into an "album" called "Photos/Videos of THE_PAGE".

These photos can be accessed by calling graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/tagged.

This is my situation...

There are currently 6 photos in this album. However, only 5 make it onto the output of the Graph call. It is not a query limit issue or anything like that. This user's photo just DOESN'T make it onto the graph call.

I thought... maybe the owner's not a fan of the page? Nope.
I thought... maybe the user's privacy settings are inhibiting this? Maybe. But I can't see the photos of a couple other owners of photos who DO show up in the graph call.

I'm going crazy! If anyone has any idea why this is happening, please help! If it is privacy settings, what settings would the user have to change?